# Export virtualbox image files from a linux box

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine

We have a Linux box that we used to have support for. but the company that supports the box went out of business.
The server (I believe is Ubuntu) was backing up our physical servers and creates an oracle VirtualBox image on demand.
When we try to create the VirtualBox instance we get the error below.

```
    2015-06-12 00:33:14  | Volume Storage Service: Reset Failover Cache
    2015-06-12 00:33:14  | Volume Storage Service: Configuring Failover cache for disk CONTROL-DC_F_27923bd6-29d0-11e0-8464-842b2b6f6fb0_4194304,
    2015-06-12 00:33:16  | Exception: workflowengine.Exceptions.ScriptFailedException Message: Script '/opt/qbase3/apps/workflowengine/tasklets/actor/volumestorageclient/diskResetFailover/scripts/volumestorageclient_configure_failovercache.rscript' on agent 'a1111111-30f7-4b99-a478-853a11583d99' for job 'ab2518e7-03df-4fd3-9e21-4906c8388c7c' failed with errorcode 1 : RECEIVED WRONG ERROR CODE FROM WRAPPER:
    ==== Agent - Volume Storage Service - Configure Failovercache ==== Error in sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/pymonkey/core/pymonkey/messages/ErrorconditionHandler.py", line 211, in _exceptionhook
     self._raise(message, level=q.enumerators.ErrorconditionLevel.CRITICAL, backtrace=backtrace )
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/pymonkey/core/pymonkey/messages/ErrorconditionHandler.py", line 57, in _raise
     raise Exception(errormessage) Exception: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'> <Fault 1: 'setFailover Caught fungi::IOException: Volume is halted due to previous errors 903d24d2c1d947ee'> <traceback object at 0x3861758>
  Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/qbase3/var/tmp/rscripts/ab2518e7-03df-4fd3-9e21-4906c8388c7c.rscript", line 28, in <module>
     q.dss.voldrv.volume.setFailover(volume,params['focIP'],params['focPort'])
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/pymonkey/extensions/volumedriver-block/DSSBlkVolumeDriver.py", line 872, in setFailover
     self._server.setFailover(params)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
     return self.__send(self.__name, args)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
     verbose=self.__verbose
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1253, in request
     return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1392, in _parse_response
     return u.close()
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 838, in close
     raise Fault(**self._stack[0]) xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: 'setFailover Caught fungi::IOException: Volume is halted due to previous errors 903d24d2c1d947ee'>
   Stacktrace: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python/site-packages/workflowengine/WFLAgentController.py", line 122, in __execute
     params = self.__agentController.executeScript(agentguid, jobguid, scriptpath, params)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python/site-packages/workflowengine/AgentController.py", line 99, in executeScript
     return self.__waitForScript(agentguid, jobguid, timeout)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python/site-packages/workflowengine/AgentController.py", line 154, in __waitForScript
     raise ScriptFailedException(jobguid, agentguid, acjob.scriptpath, acjob.errorcode, acjob.erroroutput) ScriptFailedException: Script '/opt/qbase3/apps/workflowengine/tasklets/actor/volumestorageclient/diskResetFailover/scripts/volumestorageclient_configure_failovercache.rscript' on agent 'a1111111-30f7-4b99-a478-853a11583d99' for job 'ab2518e7-03df-4fd3-9e21-4906c8388c7c' failed with errorcode 1 : RECEIVED WRONG ERROR CODE FROM WRAPPER:
    ==== Agent - Volume Storage Service - Configure Failovercache ==== Error in sys.excepthook: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/pymonkey/core/pymonkey/messages/ErrorconditionHandler.py", line 211, in _exceptionhook
     self._raise(message, level=q.enumerators.ErrorconditionLevel.CRITICAL, backtrace=backtrace )
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/pymonkey/core/pymonkey/messages/ErrorconditionHandler.py", line 57, in _raise
     raise Exception(errormessage) Exception: <class 'xmlrpclib.Fault'> <Fault 1: 'setFailover Caught fungi::IOException: Volume is halted due to previous errors 903d24d2c1d947ee'> <traceback object at 0x3861758>
  Original exception was: Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/opt/qbase3/var/tmp/rscripts/ab2518e7-03df-4fd3-9e21-4906c8388c7c.rscript", line 28, in <module>
     q.dss.voldrv.volume.setFailover(volume,params['focIP'],params['focPort'])
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/pymonkey/extensions/volumedriver-block/DSSBlkVolumeDriver.py", line 872, in setFailover
     self._server.setFailover(params)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1199, in __call__
     return self.__send(self.__name, args)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1489, in __request
     verbose=self.__verbose
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1253, in request
     return self._parse_response(h.getfile(), sock)
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 1392, in _parse_response
     return u.close()
   File "/opt/qbase3/lib/python2.6/xmlrpclib.py", line 838, in close
     raise Fault(**self._stack[0]) xmlrpclib.Fault: <Fault 1: 'setFailover Caught fungi::IOException: Volume is halted due to previous errors 903d24d2c1d947ee'>
```

I believe it has to do with the drives being bad. Any idea where to start looking? I also connected to the server using winscp and could not find the files (I think they are hidden or masked under another name) .

I can expose the target virtualbox image as a disk and connect from a windows ISCSI. but when I initialize the disk I get

> Error: Cyclic Redundancy check

Comment: Please read the [editing guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and edit your post accordingly.